# Obx not working on top of GetMaterialApp in Getx

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am trying to achieve Firebase authentication with the help of 2 separate GetPages.

If the User is logged out i must get authenticationPages and if user is logged in i want to have authenticatedPages in GetMaterialApp's getPages parameter.

To achieve it i gave GetMaterialApp inside Obx and when the authentication state changes Obx will rebuild with new getPages and initialPage.

This authentication observation is given inside AppController which decides GetPages and initialScreen.

After I execute this code and login with valid credentials.

I'm getting "User is signed in" but the GetMaterialApp widget is not rebuilding.

When i open the app again after closing i am getting HomePage.

The App is simply not rebuilding to move to Authenticated Pages from Authentication Pages when logged in or from Authentication Pages to Authenticated Pages when logged out at run time but is happening when the App is reopened.

```
void main() async
{
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
Get.put(AppController(firebaseDataLayer : FirebaseDataLayer()) , permanent: true);
Get.find\<AppController>().userInit();
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{

MyApp({super.key});
//AppController controller = Get.find\<AppController\>();
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Obx(() =\> GetMaterialApp(
title: 'My Accountant',
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
//initialBinding: AppControllerBinding(),
getPages: Get.find\<AppController\>().pages.value,
initialRoute: Get.find\<AppController\>().pageName.value,
));
}
}

/*---App Controller----*/

class AppController extends GetxController{
AppController({required this.firebaseDataLayer});
final FirebaseDataLayer firebaseDataLayer;
Rx\<User?\>? user;
late RxString pageName;
late RxList\<GetPage\> pages;
@override
onInit(){
super.onInit();
pageName = PagesOfApp.loginPageName.obs;
pages = PagesOfApp.authenticationPages.obs;
userInit();
}
void userInit(){
firebaseDataLayer.listenAuthStateChanges().listen((User? authenticatedUser) {
if (authenticatedUser == null) {
user?.value = null;
print('User is currently signed out from App!');
pageName.value = PagesOfApp.loginPageName;
pages.value=PagesOfApp.authenticationPages;
print(pages.value);
update();
} else {
print(pageName.value);
user?.value = authenticatedUser;
print('User is signed in!  ${authenticatedUser.email}  and ${user?.value}');
pageName.value = PagesOfApp.homePage;
print(pageName.value);
pages.value=PagesOfApp.authenticatedPages;
print(pages.value);
update();
}
});
}
}

/*-----PagesOfApp----*/

class PagesOfApp{
PagesOfApp._();
static String loginPageName = '/login';
static String homePage = '/home';

//Pages to authenticate the User
static var authenticationPages =[
GetPage(name: '/login', page:()=> UserLoginPage(),binding: UserLoginBinding()),
GetPage(name: '/register', page:()=> UserRegisterScreen() , binding: UserRegisterBinding() , transition: Transition.leftToRight)];

//Pages to appear after successful authentication of User
static final authenticatedPages = [
GetPage(name: '/home', page: ()=>HomePage())];
}
```